# MIPS: Instruction Memory: Referring to instruction in memory

Tags: mips

I'm implementing MIPS processor using Verilog.

```
input   [31:0] address;
output [31:0] instruction;
reg [31:0] instruction_memory [255:0];
assign instruction = instruction_memory[address[9:2]];
```

This is an almost complete body of *Instruction Memory* module.
The thing I cannot understand is why we refer to the instruction in memory using *address[**9:2**]*. I mean, why **[9:2]** ?

I've found an answer, but I cannot understand it. It says:

> What bits select the first 256 words? **[9:2]**!

Can you, please, explain me this detail in some other, more understandable way?
Thank you.

Comment: For various reasons, the address of the instruction, or the PC value is specified in units of bytes. However your instruction memory is organized to be addressed in words. This design converts byte address into word address by shifting the address 2 bits to the right (e.g. byte address 0x80 becomes word address 0x20). The lower two bits are ignored because they are assumed to be always be 0s.

Comment: @user3528438 I've added the implementation to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because MIPS instructions are all 32 bits in length, bits 0 and 1 don't hold any meaning. Therefore instead of looking at `[7:0]` of the address it looks at `[9:2]`, which is the translation for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example.

A stack ( the decimal numbers to the left are intended to be used for this brief explanation ). The binary numbers to the right are the addresses of the instructions in the instruction memory (the values aren't real. Just an example.)

---

So on...

1 | 0000 10**00**  ***>> Address(Instruct 3)***

---

2 | 0000 0111

3 | 0000 0110

4 | 0000 0101

5 | 0000 01**00**   ***>> Address(Instruct 2)***

---

6 | 0000 0011

7 | 0000 0010

8 | 0000 0001

9 | 0000 00**00**    ***>> Address(Instruct 1)***

In MIPS, an instruction is 4 byte long. That is why, as you can see from example above, that going from *Instruct 1* (l. 9) to *Instruct 2* (l. 5), we are actually "stepping" over 4 lines ( 9, 8, 7, 6 ), that is adding to *0000 0000*, 4. As *Instruct 2* is reached, it is obvious that the first two bits(in bold) remain unchanged. And again, adding *Address(Instruct 2) + 4*, we reach *Instruct 3*. Here, the first two bits have not changed.

The result will be the same for an infinite number of instructions.

So the conclusion is: the first two bits doesn't tell us anything. They do not change as we go from instruction to instruction. It's a good reason to neglect them.
 The ones that are useful are bits starting from position 2.

---

Here's the instruction memory implementation:

[image]

Comment: GC I understand why first two bits are not included, but what about bit 8 and 9? The address must actually be {address[7:2],2'b00} or address[7:0].  Adding extra bits 8 and 9 will be wrong. Am I correct?

Comment: @user3219492 It's been a long time ago, but as I see now: I didn't neglect bits 8 and 9, I could have put them, but I wanted to specifically emphasize that first 2 bits are meaningless (after all I wrote in my question condition that instruction memory should be referred to as: instruction_memory[address[9:2]];).

Comment: @user3219492 So, adding extra bits 8 and 9 will be Correct.

But, generally, an instruction is 4 bytes long in MIPS. I could have typed them all, but what's the use ?! =)

Comment: I didn't find an answer for my question:  **what is the use of bits 8 and 9.** Can you elaborate?  And in your edited code, instruction memory is 128 different 4 bytes. As it is 128, the address width has to be 7 bits. But you are using 9:2 which is 8 bits.

Comment: @user3219492 I guess my code isn't correct at this place. I wrote it 1 year ago, so I'm looking at this question just as you do. Because 'address[9:2]' and 'NENTRIES' are related,  one of them should be changed (address[8:2] or NENTRIES=256). What do you think about this?

Comment: Yes, this looks correct.

Comment: @user3219492 Ok.